# Asymptotic expansion of Fourier integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

In the book of *perturbation techniques* by Nayfeh, at page 63, it is given that

> As a fourth example, we consider the Fourier integral
> $$
> I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i \alpha t} f(t) d t
> $$
> ...
> $$
> I(\alpha)=-\frac{f(0)}{i \alpha}-\frac{1}{i \alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i \alpha t} f^{\prime}(t) d t
> $$
> Continuing the process as in the preceding example, we obtain
> $$
> I(\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{(-i \alpha)^{n+1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{N+2}}\right)
> $$
> which is an asymptotic expansion.

However, if $
I(\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{(-i \alpha)^{n+1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{N+2}}\right)$ was an asymptotic expansion, then the coefficient of
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
term would need to be independent of $\alpha$, but the coefficient, namely the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i \alpha t} f^{\prime}(t) d t,$$
is NOT independent of $\alpha$, so this expansion is not an asymptotic expansion.

Am I missing something in here?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. Consider the function $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}(1-e^{-x})$. The coefficient of $1/x$ depends on $x$, still $f(x)=1+1/x+O(1/x^2)$ is an asymptotic expansion, no?

Comment: @Mindlack going from the former to the latter requires explanation and the proof that $e^{-x}/x = O(1/x^2)$. I'm asking what the corresponding explanation in this case

Comment: Ok: then $\left|\int_0^{\infty}{e^{i\alpha t}f^{(n)}(t)dt}\right| \leq \|f^{(n)}\|_{L^1}$, which should be enough, I think.